# Exclude nomenclature and glossary from page count

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, nomencl

I want both, the nomenclature and glossary, be excluded from the page count.
They are not appearing in the toc yet they still increases my number of pages.
How can I say from which page on my total number of pages shall begin?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 ...
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
 ...
\end{abstract}
\newglossaryentry{cdc}
{
name=CDC, description={Center for Disease Control}
}
\newglossaryentry{lstm}
{
name=LSTM, description={Long Short Term Memory}
}
...
\printglossaries

\nomenclature[M]{$\phi$}{...Activation function in a neural network}

\nomenclature[M]{\textbf{v}}{...bold and lower case letters represents a vector}

\printnomenclature
\tableofcontents
\chapter{..}
%myblabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have tried. How do you get your page count?

Comment: Try to use frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter. Put glossaries and appendix in the backmatter.

Comment: shall be more clear now, thanks Peter for telling me!
Will try it now with Frontmatter and this stuff today and get back to you guys

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Raffaele it is working with commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 ...
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
 ...
\end{abstract}
\newglossaryentry{cdc}
{
name=CDC, description={Center for Disease Control}
}
\newglossaryentry{lstm}
{
name=LSTM, description={Long Short Term Memory}
}
...
\printglossaries

\nomenclature[M]{$\phi$}{...Activation function in a neural network}

\nomenclature[M]{\textbf{v}}{...bold and lower case letters represents a vector}

\printnomenclature
\tableofcontents
\chapter{..}
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%myblabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried the MWE you gave in your answer and there are many problems with it. Did you try it? There are all sorts of `undefined control sequence` one of which is `\mainmatter`. It appears from your MWE that you don't want to count page numbers of the ToC, the Abstract, and other preliminaries. Why did you not say that in your question? The `report` class does not have the `\...matter` commands but `book` does. I suggest that you provide an answer that works or delete your current one. --- GOM